Issue with Firestore Document Updates in Batch: Only the Last Update is Applied
I’m encountering a problem with updating multiple documents in Firestore using batch operations. My goal is to decrement the quantity of items in a cart, where items can come from either catalogs or testers. The issue is that when I try to update multiple stock documents, only the last update seems to be applied, even though all updates appear as successful in the console.

Context
Navigation to CashRegisterViewController:
For each item, I retrieve the idParent and idDocument corresponding to the item.
I then perform quantity updates for stock documents or update a field for tester documents.
Issue Encountered:
When there are multiple catalog items, the decrement only happens for the last document in the cart. Previous updates are overwritten, and only the last document is updated correctly.
When dealing with multiple testers, everything works fine, and each tester is updated as expected.

Observations
When updating stock documents, quantities are decremented correctly in the console, but only the last update is applied to Firestore.
Tester updates work correctly.

Questions
Why are stock updates only applied to the last document?
How can I fix this issue to ensure that all stock updates are applied correctly?
Thank you in advance for your help!


import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

class CashRegisterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var clientNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var clientPointsTextField: DesignableTextField!

    var client: Client?
    var idParent: String?
    var idDocument: String?
    var category: String?
    var selectedSegmentIndex: Int? 

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Configurez la tableView
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
            
            if let client = client {
                clientNameLabel.text = "\(client.nom) \(client.prénom)"
                clientPointsTextField.text = "\(client.points)"
            } else {
                clientNameLabel.text = "Acheteur non client"
                clientPointsTextField.text = "0"
                clientNameLabel.isHidden = true
            }
            
            // Charger les articles du panier depuis ShoppingCart
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

        private func removeItem(at index: Int) {
            ShoppingCart.shared.removeItem(at: index)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        }

        private func duplicateItem(at index: Int) {
            let itemToDuplicate = ShoppingCart.shared.items[index]
            ShoppingCart.shared.addItem(itemToDuplicate)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: ShoppingCart.shared.items.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        }

        @IBAction func paymentTypeAction(_ sender: Any) {
            let paymentAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Choisissez le type de paiement", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let card = UIAlertAction(title: "Carte", style: .default, handler: nil)
            let cash = UIAlertAction(title: "Espèce", style: .default, handler: nil)
            let payPal = UIAlertAction(title: "PayPal", style: .default, handler: nil)
            paymentAlert.addAction(card)
            paymentAlert.addAction(cash)
            paymentAlert.addAction(payPal)
            self.present(paymentAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return ShoppingCart.shared.items.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CashCell", for: indexPath) as? CashTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("La cellule de type CashTableViewCell n'a pas pu être défilée.")
            }

            let index = indexPath.row
            let item = ShoppingCart.shared.items[index]
            cell.ReferenceLabel.text = item.reference
            cell.typeLabel.text = item.type
            cell.priceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", item.price)

            //cell.addButton.isHidden = false
            
            cell.addButton.isHidden = false
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
           
            cell.onDeleteButtonTapped = { [weak self] in
                self?.removeItem(at: index)
            }
            cell.onAddButtonTapped = { [weak self] in
                self?.duplicateItem(at: index)
            }

            return cell
        }
    
    //Cadeau
    @IBAction func cadeauButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        showGiftOptionsAlert()
    }
    private func showGiftOptionsAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choisissez un cadeau", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let encensAction = UIAlertAction(title: "encens", style: .default) { _ in
            self.navigateToHouseCatalogue(segmentIndex: 3, applyPriceFilter: true) // Index pour Encens
        }
        let desodorisantAction = UIAlertAction(title: "désodorisant", style: .default) { _ in
            self.navigateToHouseCatalogue(segmentIndex: 0) // Index pour Désodorisant
        }
        
        alert.addAction(encensAction)
        alert.addAction(desodorisantAction)
        
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func navigateToHouseCatalogue(segmentIndex: Int, applyPriceFilter: Bool = false) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let houseCatalogueVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HouseCatalogueViewController") as? HouseCatalogueViewController {
            houseCatalogueVC.selectedSegmentIndex = segmentIndex
            houseCatalogueVC.applyPriceFilterForEncens = applyPriceFilter
            houseCatalogueVC.isGiftNavigation = true

            navigationController?.pushViewController(houseCatalogueVC, animated: true)
        }
    }


    private func handleGiftSelection(_ giftType: String) {
        print("Cadeau sélectionné : \(giftType)")
        
        let segmentIndex: Int
        switch giftType {
        case "Encens":
            segmentIndex = 3 // Index pour le segment Encens
        case "Désodorisant":
            segmentIndex = 0 // Index pour le segment Désodorisant
        default:
            return
        }
        
        navigateToHouseCatalogue(segmentIndex: segmentIndex)
    }



        @IBAction func clearCartButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            ShoppingCart.shared.clearCart()
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    

        @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            let batch = db.batch() // Crée un batch pour les mises à jour groupées

            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup() // Utilisé pour synchroniser les tâches asynchrones

            // Pour les mises à jour des testeurs
            for item in ShoppingCart.shared.items {
                let reference = item.reference
                let type = item.type
                
                switch item.origin {
                case .tester:
                    dispatchGroup.enter() // Entrée dans le groupe pour chaque tâche asynchrone

                    // Filtre les documents dans la collection "testeurs" par référence
                    let initialQuery = db.collection("testeurs")
                        .whereField("reference", isEqualTo: reference)
                    
                    initialQuery.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Erreur lors de la récupération des documents du testeur: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            dispatchGroup.leave() // Sortie du groupe en cas d'erreur
                            return
                        }

                        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                            print("Aucun document trouvé pour la référence \(reference).")
                            dispatchGroup.leave() // Sortie du groupe si aucun document trouvé
                            return
                        }

                        // Filtrage par type et tri par date en mémoire
                        let filteredAndSortedDocuments = documents.filter { document in
                            let data = document.data()
                            let documentType = data["type"] as? String
                            let documentDate = data["date"] as? Timestamp
                            return documentType == type && documentDate != nil
                        }.sorted { ($0.data()["date"] as? Timestamp)?.seconds ?? 0 > ($1.data()["date"] as? Timestamp)?.seconds ?? 0 }
                        
                        if let mostRecentDocument = filteredAndSortedDocuments.first {
                            // Met à jour le champ "state" en "vendu" dans le batch pour le document le plus récent
                            batch.updateData(["state": "vendu"], forDocument: mostRecentDocument.reference)
                        }
                        
                        dispatchGroup.leave() // Sortie du groupe après la mise à jour
                    }   
                    
                case .stock:
                    guard let idParent = self.idParent,
                          let idDocument = self.idDocument,
                          let category = self.category else {
                        print("Variables nécessaires non définies pour le stock")
                        continue // Passer à l'article suivant
                    }

                    dispatchGroup.enter() // Entrée dans le groupe pour chaque tâche asynchrone
                    
                    let documentRef = db.collection("stocks").document(idParent).collection("produits").document(idDocument)

                    documentRef.getDocument { [weak self] (documentSnapshot, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Erreur lors de la récupération du document du produit: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            dispatchGroup.leave() // Sortie du groupe en cas d'erreur
                            return
                        }

                        guard let productData = documentSnapshot?.data(),
                              let currentQuantity = productData["quantité"] as? Int else {
                            print("Quantité non trouvée dans le document ou n'est pas un entier")
                            dispatchGroup.leave() // Sortie du groupe si quantité non trouvée
                            return
                        }

                        if currentQuantity > 0 {
                            let newQuantity = currentQuantity - 1
                            batch.updateData(["quantité": newQuantity], forDocument: documentRef)
                            print("Quantité mise à jour pour le produit: \(documentRef), nouvelle quantité: \(newQuantity)")
                        } else {
                            print("Quantité insuffisante pour décrémenter.")
                        }

                        dispatchGroup.leave() // Sortie du groupe après la mise à jour
                    }
                }
            }

            // Appeler batch.commit après que toutes les mises à jour soient terminées
            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                print("Commit du batch de mises à jour")
                batch.commit { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Erreur lors de la mise à jour des documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        print("Documents mis à jour avec succès.")
                    }
                }
                // Nettoyer le panier après l'enregistrement
                ShoppingCart.shared.clearCart()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }



There's a lot going on in the code, but my guess is that you have updates going on in parallel. Consider using the server-side increment operation (i.e. increment(-1) instead of the let newQuantity = currentQuantity - 1 you have now: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value

Hello,
Thank you for your suggestion. I tried using the server-side increment operation as recommended, but unfortunately, it did not resolve the issue.
The problem I’m facing is as follows: when handling the "case .stock", if there are multiple items in the cart, the quantity update only applies to the last item processed. It seems that updates for the other items are either overwritten or ignored.

I understood the problem already. There's just a lot of code (quite some of it not relevant) in the question, which makes it harder to figure out what's going wrong. If you've tried my suggestion and the logic still fails, update your question with the new code - after studying How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (read it please, it's quite useful and makes it much more likely that we can help).

If you encounter problems, it's best to create a MCVE when posting a question. You posted almost 300 (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's way too much code for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read how to ask a question.

Hi,
Sorry for the way I asked the question. I'm a beginner, which is why I provided the complete code for my view. I’ll try to rephrase, but anyway, the problem I have is caused by the "saveButtonTapped" function in the "case .stock" section. When I click the button, the desired decrement doesn’t apply to all documents but only to the data in the last added document.
